# Is there anyway to remove a row in mysql automatically? Nodejs, my-sql

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb

In mongodb with mongoose we can remove data automatically like this:
 `expiresAt:{`
`type: Date,`
`default: Date.now(),`
`index: {`
`expireAfterSeconds: 500,`
`},`
`},`

But in mysql I cant find any solution for this. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the Event Scheduler to start a query every secs,mins,.... if

you have a timestamp

see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html